# WCF Service hosted on IIS website with TransferMode = Streamed throws w3wp.exe OutOfMemory exception?

Tags: wcf

I have build a WCF service to upload and download files.

Service: Hosted on IIS asp.net website:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileTransferService
{
 [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
 void Upload(FileTransferRequest request);
}

[MessageContract()]
public class FileTransferRequest
{
 [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
 public string FileName;

 [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
 public System.IO.Stream Data;

}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode= AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class FileTransferService : IFileTransferService
{
 public FileTransferService()
 {
  HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

  if (httpContext != null)
  {
   httpContext.Response.BufferOutput = false;
  }
 }

 public void Upload(FileTransferRequest request)
 {
  string fileName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + request.FileName;

  if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"] == null)
  {
   throw new ApplicationException("Missing upload path");
  }

  string uploadPath = "/OutputFeeds";
  string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uploadPath)), fileName);

  FileStream fs = null;
  try
  {
   fs = File.Create(filePath);
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int read = 0;
   while ((read = request.Data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
   {
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
   }
  }
  finally
  {
   if (fs != null)
   {
    fs.Close();
    fs.Dispose();
   }

   if (request.Data != null)
   {
    request.Data.Close();
    request.Data.Dispose();
   }
  }
 }    
}
```

Server config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="HttpBinding_MTOM" messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
   <security mode="None">
   <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
   </security>
  </binding>

 </bindings>
 <services>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="FileTransferServiceBehavior"
  name="FileTransferService">
  <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding_MTOM"
   contract="IFileTransferService">
   <identity>
   <dns value="localhost" />
   </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

 </services>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>

  <behavior name="FileTransferServiceBehavior">
   <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
   <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
  </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Client:  Calling the above service from console application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransferService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
     allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
     messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
     <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="">
       <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
      </transport>
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
     </security>
    </binding>

   </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
   <endpoint address="http://ht/FileTransferService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransferService"
    contract="HobbyTown.IFileTransferService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransferService" />

  </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client Upload Code:

```
 string inputFile = @"C:\Client\InputFeeds\FullInventory.zip";
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
 {
    FileTransferServiceClient proxy = new FileTransferServiceClient();
    proxy.Upload("Inventory.Zip", fs);
    //proxy.Upload(trIn);
 }
```

Note: If I change transfer mode to buffered in the client it works and however if Make the transfer mode on the client to Streamed it doesn't and throws outofmemory error.

Another [post for same problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/d36bf53e-dcb1-4df4-b26a-f692e85e6637)

Comment: What happens if you don't use `using` for the file stream on the client?

Answer (score 0):

I would wonder if the stream isn't being forced to behave as buffered on the service side. What is FileTransferRequest -- is that third-party? Streaming in WCF generally requires the stream be the only parameter in your exposed service method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

"Note that adding a second parameter to the following Echo or ProvideInfo operations causes the service model to revert back to a buffered strategy and use the run-time serialization representation of the stream. Only operations with a single input stream parameter are compatible with end-to-end request streaming.

This rule similarly applies to message contracts. As shown in the following message contract, you can have only a single body member in your message contract that is a stream. If you want to communicate additional information with the stream, this information must be a carried in message headers. The message body is exclusively reserved for the stream content."

Comment: `FileTransferRequest` is message contract shown in the example and it is defined correctly.

Comment: @andrewbadera Like Ladislav mentioned....FilesTransferRequest is message contract and it does work when the transfer mode is set to "Buffered" on the client and set to "Streamed" on the server. @Ladislav Mrnka ...I want the both sides to be Streamed transfer mode

Comment: Right; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx -- now quoted above.

Comment: But the message HAS only second parameter. The second parameter is custom soap header which is buffered always. This doesn't break streaming over http.

Comment: @andrewbadera 

 I changed the service contract as per your suggestion however it didnt' work and same exception.

Comment: @andrewbadera is there any place I can upload complete project and can you take a look what's wrong?